# MySQL join query to get the parent name of the selected records?

Tags: join, mysqli

I am trying to create a autosuggest. I have a table looks like below one.
What i am trying to achieve is that, when user enter some value the query should return the location name,and it parent name.

For E.G: when user type 'EF', the query should pull the record DEF,EFK with its parent name ABC. So that i can display the output like "DEF,ABC","EFK,ABC". Hope you got the idea? please help me.

```
+----------------+----------------+--------+
| l_id           | location_name  | parent |
+----------------+----------------+--------+
| 1              | ABC            | 0      |
| 2              | DEF            | 1      |
| 3              | EFK            | 1      |
| 4              | KLM            | 2      |
+----------------+----------------+--------+

SELECT 
  l0.`location_name`,l0.`location_id`,l1.`location_name`,l1.`location_id`,
FROM 
  location l0 
JOIN 
  location l1 ON l1.`location_id` = l0.`location_parent`
WHERE 
  l0.`location_name` LIKE "EF%"
```

But the above query throwing error.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
  location l0 JOIN location l1 ON l1.`location_id` = l0.`location_pare' at line 3
```

Comment: so whats the problem? whats happening? change the `LIKE` filter to `%EF%`

Comment: The query throwing error. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; on  location l0
JOIN
  location l1 ON l1.`location_id` = l0.`location_pare' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a comma at the end of your field list.

```
SELECT 
  l0.`location_name`,l0.`location_id`,l1.`location_name`,l1.`location_id`
FROM 
  location l0 
JOIN 
  location l1 ON l1.`location_id` = l0.`location_parent`
WHERE 
  l0.`location_name` LIKE "EF%"
```

Comment: Oh man.. @idstam.. Thanks you so much.. i didn't even noticed it.. spent a lot time to figure this out without noticing the comma.. :).